# Sendmail issues sending to a relay server

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta

Ok, so i've run into somewhat of a roadblock and can't seem to find where i'm going wrong...

I have sendmail on a Ubuntu machine running asterisk... I want sendmail to send email to a relay server I have set up that is using Postfix...  The email is not getting accepted by the relay server... so I think I may be missing something in the config...

Here's what I have so far ---

In the Postfix Log ---

```
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<root@asterisk.com>
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<root@asterisk.com>
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:20 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747498]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jan 19 07:49:20 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747498]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<root@asterisk.com>
Jan 19 07:49:20 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:20 plesk-server psa-pc-remote[3822896]: Message aborted.
Jan 19 07:49:20 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747498]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8


Postfix - main.cf
```

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
# myorigin = /etc/mailname

    myhostname = postfix.domain.com
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
    biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
    append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
# delay_warning_time = 4h

    readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
    compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file

    smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
    smtp_tls_security_level = may
# smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# smtp_enforce_tls = yes
```

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = postfix.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.domain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = [relay2.domain.com]:587
mynetworks = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/certs
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_use_tls = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
authorized_flush_users = 
authorized_mailq_users = 
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 10240000
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
smtputf8_enable = no
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /opt/psa/etc/dhparams2048.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+SHA256+AES128:EECDH+SHA384+AES256:EECDH+SHA1+AES128:EECDH+SHA1+AES256:EECDH+HIGH:AESGCM+AES128:AESGCM+AES256:CHACHA20:SHA256+AES128:SHA256+AES256:SHA1+AES128:SHA1+AES256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!KRB5:!aECDH:!kDH:!EDH
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient


smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous






In the Sendmail Log ---
```

```
Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sendmail[1081803]: 40JCnKct1081803: from=root@Asterisk.com, size=91, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202401191249.40JCnKct1081803@Asteri>
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sm-mta[1081804]: 40JCnKYc1081804: from=<root@Asterisk.com>, size=485, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202401191249.40JCnKct1081803@Aster>
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sendmail[1081803]: 40JCnKct1081803: to=<support@domain.com>, ctladdr=root@Asterisk.com (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00>
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sm-mta[1081806]: STARTTLS=client, relay=relay.domain.com., version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sm-mta[1081806]: 40JCnKYc1081804: to=<support@domain.com>, ctladdr=<root@Asterisk.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00>
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sm-mta[1081806]: 40JCnKYc1081804: 40JCnKYc1081806: DSN: Service unavailable
    Jan 19 07:49:20 Asterisk sm-mta[1081806]: 40JCnKYc1081806: to=<root@Asterisk.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, sta>
```

```
Sendmail.mc
```

```
    divert(-1)dnl

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Sendmail: debproto.mc,v 8.15.2 2020-03-08 00:39:49 cowboy Exp $
#
# Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
# cf/debian/sendmail.mc.  Generated from sendmail.mc.in by configure.
#
# sendmail.mc prototype config file for building Sendmail 8.15.2
#
# Note: the .in file supports 8.7.6 - 9.0.0, but the generated
#   file is customized to the version noted above.
#
# This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
# If you modify this file, you will have to regenerate /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# by running this file through the m4 preprocessor via one of the following:
#   * make   (or make -C /etc/mail)
#   * sendmailconfig
#   * m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# The first two options are preferred as they will also update other files
# that depend upon the contents of this file.
#
# The best documentation for this .mc file is:
# /usr/share/doc/sendmail-doc/cf.README.gz
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    divert(0)dnl
#
#   Copyright (c) 1998-2005 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
#  This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
```

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `relay.domain.com')dnl
    define(`RELAY_MAILER',`esmtp')dnl
    define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl


    define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
    include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
    VERSIONID(`$Id: sendmail.mc, v 8.15.2-18 2020-03-08 00:39:49 cowboy Exp $')
    OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
    DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl

    dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE

    undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        #DAEMON_HOSTSTATS=

    dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
    dnl #
    dnl # General defines
    dnl #
    dnl # SAFE_FILE_ENV: [undefined] If set, sendmail will do a chroot()
    dnl #   into this directory before writing files.
    dnl #   If *all* your user accounts are under /home then use that
    dnl #   instead - it will prevent any writes outside of /home !
    dnl #   define(`confSAFE_FILE_ENV',             `')dnl
    dnl #
    dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
    dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
    dnl # If you want to support IPv6, switch the commented/uncommentd lines
    dnl #

    FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
    dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
    DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
    dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
    DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # Be somewhat anal in what we allow

    define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',dnl
    needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # Define connection throttling and window length

    define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `15')dnl
    define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`10m')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # Features
    dnl #
    dnl # use /etc/mail/local-host-names

    FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # The access db is the basis for most of sendmail's checking

    FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # The greet_pause feature stops some automail bots - but check the
    dnl # provided access db for details on excluding localhosts...

    FEATURE(`greet_pause', `1000')dnl 1 seconds

    dnl #
    dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking

    FEATURE(`delay_checks', `friend', `n')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # If we get too many bad recipients, slow things down...

    define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE',`3')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # Stop connections that overflow our concurrent and time connection rates

    FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
    FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # If you're on a dialup link, you should enable this - so sendmail
    dnl # will not bring up the link (it will queue mail for later)
    dnl define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE',`True')dnl
    dnl #
    dnl # Dialup/LAN connection overrides
    dnl #

    include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
    include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl

    dnl #
    dnl # Masquerading options

    FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
    MASQUERADE_AS(`asterisk.domain.com')dnl
    FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
    FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl



    dnl #
    dnl # Default Mailer setup

    MAILER_DEFINITIONS
    MAILER(`local')dnl
    MAILER(`smtp')dnl
```

Additional Logs --

Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sendmail[1100425]: 40NEOr961100425: from=info@domain.com, size=136, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=202401231424.40NEOr961100425@Asterisk.kqicqtms5eeezejjspbgv3d4tf.bx.inter
Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sm-mta[1100426]: 40NEOrVV1100426: from=info@domain.com, size=451, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=202401231424.40NEOr961100425@Asterisk.kqicqtms5eeezejjspbgv3d4tf.bx.inter
Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sendmail[1100425]: 40NEOr961100425: to=info@domain.com, ctladdr=info@domain.com (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30136, relay=[12>
Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: STARTTLS=client, relay=relay.domain.com., version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100426: to=info@domain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120451, relay=relay.domain.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], >
Jan 23 09:24:53 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100426: 40NEOrVV1100428: DSN: Service unavailable
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100428: to=info@domain.com, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30000, relay=relay.domain.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], d>
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100428: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100428: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100428: 40NEOrVW1100428: return to sender: User unknown
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVW1100428: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jan 23 09:24:54 Asterisk sm-mta[1100428]: 40NEOrVV1100428: Saved message in /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Jan 19 07:49:07 plesk-server postfix/smtpd[1747495]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<root@asterisk.com>
```

is postfix complaining that somebody is trying to give it an email without a valid RCPT FROM header.

When you open a SMTP session to postfix, it expects you to give it

HELO (initiating session)
MAIL FROM (sender)
RCTP TO (recipient)
DATA (body of the mail)

by the way there is from and MAIL FROM. from is in the body, and you can set it to whatever you want (most mailservers dont complain if it does not match MAIL FROM). MAIL FROM is whats used to actually route emails.
Ironically most mail clients show you only the `from` from the body. It will also be used if you click on "reply".

Not sure why its printing this - did you redact this before posting?

```
unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

Long story short, your mail client is not setting the recipient correctly. Seems to be an issue on sendmails side, postfix looks ok here.

Can you post the cli command you use to send mails? Something like this:

`echo body_content | mail -s testsubject -a "From: sender@example.com" recipient@example.com`

This will set the MAIL FROM to sender@example.com

By the way this `# smtp_enforce_tls = yes` you can forget, 90% of mail servers out there have a TLS certificate installed but its not for the respective domain or its expired.
you can turn it on, but then your mailserver wont talk to anybody, which would be the desired behavior.
Sadly email in general is a bit broken.
If you only relay mails with that postifx, and your relay server has working TLS, good for you ;) then enable it.

If you get sick of postfix (I don't like it, its to bloated) you can give OpenSMTPD a shot. Its much simpler to setup and understand and I have a mostly working config for a relay host with lots of comments for understand for you here: https://www.blunix.com/manual/baseline/functions/mailrelay/#etcsmtpdconf-in-detail

Comment: Yes I had redacted the IP addresses and emails to avoid problems once this was posted...

the command I was using was simply

mail info@domain.com

Then I would fill out the info it requested like subject and such... then CTRL-D to send it out...   never was able to get it to work...

Comment: paste me the whole command you used to send mails (or try mine and let me know if it works)

Comment: Didn't work with your command either...  I will post the log in the next message because it won't let me post it here in the reply...

Comment: you can use paste.debian.net to paste lots of code if stackoverflow wont let you